# Documentation for meta-data and vendor-data

Tags: autoinstall

We could not find any document related to meta-data and vendor-data used in autoinstall, when to use one or the other.
Please share any relevant documentation related to autoinstall's meta-data and vendor-data with appropriate examples for each of the autoinstall files.